# Generate an HTML table from a Word Document

Tags: javascript, html, xml, database, parsing

I'm putting together a simple website for our department. I'd like to include one of the references that we use often on the main page, a word document that contains a priority list for outstanding work. This document is generated by another department and located on a shared drive. The info is not in a table, but uses a fairly consisten format for displaying info.

Ex: (the info is actually formatted like this)

```
--------------
Item Title
--------------
Tracker#: 12345-0012 Due; 01/01/12
Description...
```

My ultimate goal is to have a table on the main page that contains the various items in the priority list. I would like a mechanism that automatically checks the word docs about once an hour, parses the document, generates a table from the info in the doc, and updates the main page accordingly.

I've never done anything like this and have no idea where to start or if what I'm asking is even possible. I'm not in IT and do not have the ability to use ASP or PHP at the moment. So I'd like to avoid server-side scripting if possible, but I may be able to work something out if absolutely necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want a windows app that writes to a html file that is also stored on the shared drive?

Comment: The HTML file is on a different network drive. One department updates the word doc periodically and we have to check the file periodically. It would be nice if the contents could be displayed in an HTML table (not just linking ti the doc)

Comment: Do you have any programming experience or do you have a programmer that can work on this?

Comment: I've programmed micro-controllers in C and C+. I've also done some basic stuff in Java. I has hoping there was something out there already that could do what I wanted...

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this in java.. you can use the docx4j library.. Without that it would be difficult. Can't the team that create the doc store the file as a flat file as well maybe?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to save document as html (using automation - create Word.Application object, call Open, SaveAs) and serve it directly or inside frame.